# Sails, How to insert record with collection of child table?

Tags: sails.js

I have model use which contain list of `userRole` collection, and I want to send data from angularjs and insert to database.

```
//MODEL: User.js
module.exports =
{
  autoPK: false,
  attributes:
  {
    id          : {type: 'integer',  primaryKey: true, columnName: 'id'},
    firstName   : {type:'string', required:true},
    lastName    : {type:'string', required:true},
    phone       : {type:'string', required:true, unique: true},
    roles       : {collection:'UserRole', via:'user'}
  }
}


//MODEL: UserRole.js
module.exports =
{
  autoPK: false,
  attributes:
  {
    user: {model: 'user'},
    code: {type: 'string', required:true},
    //a composite index
    indexes:[{
      attributes:  ['user', 'code'],
      unique: true
    }]
  }
};
```

When I post data from angular following these example, I got and error on sail lift.

```
{
    "data":{
        "firstName":"Administrator",
        "lastName":"AD",
        "phone":"7924499995",
        "roles":[
            {"code":"admin"},
            {"code":"manager"},
            {"code":"officer"}
        ]
    }
}
```

The error is :

```
Unable to parse HTTP body- error occurred :: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected string\n    at Object.parse (native)\n    at parse (C:\\Users\\Chanatipy\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_
modules\\sails\\node_modules\\body-parser\\lib\\types\\json.js:66:17)\n    at C:\\Users\\Chanatipy\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sails\\node_modules\\body-parser\\lib\\rea
d.js:91:18\n    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\\Users\\Chanatipy\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\sails\\node_modules\\raw-body\\index.js:136:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.g (even
ts.js:260:16)\n    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)\n    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:4
52:9)\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:407:17)'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In case of no collection, my project work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It look like that Sails ORM not support to save relation object, so I will try to save relation object after create/update parent object.

I will put the coding in 'afterCreate' function of the parent model.

```js
//MODEL: User.js
module.exports =
{
  autoPK: false,
  attributes:
  {
    id          : {type: 'integer',  primaryKey: true, columnName: 'id'},
    firstName   : {type:'string', required:true},
    lastName    : {type:'string', required:true},
    phone       : {type:'string', required:true, unique: true},
    roles       : {collection:'UserRole', via:'user'}
  },
  afterCreate:function (attributes, next) {
    //TODO insert/update child collections he
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `beforeValidate` hook and the `findOrCreate` method. This way, you will create missing roles on the fly.

```js
//MODEL: User.js
module.exports =
{
  autoPK: false,
  attributes:
  {
    id          : {type: 'integer',  primaryKey: true, columnName: 'id'},
    firstName   : {type:'string', required:true},
    lastName    : {type:'string', required:true},
    phone       : {type:'string', required:true, unique: true},
    roles       : {collection:'UserRole', via:'user'}
  }

  beforeValidate: (user, cb) => {
    UserRole.findOrUpdate(
      // { code: ['admin', 'manager', 'officer']} in your case
      { code: _.pluck(user.roles, 'code') },
      user.roles,
      (error, roles) => {
        user.roles = roles;
        cb();
    );
  }
}
```